# Comparation returns true when it shouldn't

Tags: c#

This is my UserData class:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserData
{
    public string currentGame;
    public int score;
    public string name;

    public UserData(string name) => this.name = name;  
}
```

[image]

If instead of `var b = userData != user;` I use `var b = !userData.Equals(user);` it drops also true.
I want to compare the values, but seems like it works with the references...

Comment: This might be an interesting read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "it drops also true". Also, we have no idea whether `UserData` overrides the `Equals` method. By default it *will* compare references, yes. Please provide a [mcve], showing the code as *text* rather than just an image. (The image can be useful to show the debugger, but shouldn't be the only way the code is shown.)

Comment: I will try this, seems like it's what I was searching for. I though != performed a value equality check and Equals a reference one but seems like not. I'm gonna create my Equals override and if it works, I'll close the thread. If you desire just write a common answer in order to give your green check, ty so much.

Comment: @RubénCantón: No, it's typically the other way round - overriding `Equals` is more common than overloading the `==` operator (although both are possible, and without *any* extra code, they'll do the same thing).

Comment: @RubénCantón indeed `Equals` and `==` are  usually the same, and they can be both overriden (independently!).

Comment: Ty, I just overrided it and works as expected, plz give me an answer instead of a comment to be able to green check you :)